# Custom post type returns bad post ID

Tags: custom-post-types, id

I added custom post type and I have first problem.

I don't know why but if I use `$post->ID`, independently of post ID it always gave me the same value. I'm using this function `<?php the_post(); ?>` to display content of post. What can I do with it?

Comment: Please add proper context, without seeing your code it will be hard to help you. Please file an [edit] with your code and context

Comment: Are you added global $post; in top ?

Comment: @Yatendra the `$post` global is set by the `the_post()`, so without that, it does not really matter ;-)

Comment: Thanks for help now i can display real ID of post. But i meet next problem when i try to get author name or other his meta it show me wrong author. In backend i selected author with ID 7, but in post page it shows me author with id 5. Why? There is my code: http://paste.ofcode.org/n2VFmvVcqspJcZeMx7jM6k

Comment: Which value does it always return? Is there a particular reason `get_the_ID` doesn't work? Can we see your code? Is this a main loop or a custom loop?

Comment: @Sebastian this isn't a forum, comments and discussion go here, only post an answer if you believe you've got a solution. Then you can then mark the correct answer as accepted to award reputation points

Answer (score 1):

Use the following before `$post->ID` in your code:

```
global $post
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `the_post`, it sets the value of `$post`, and will do so every time you call it. They give you the same value because they are the **same** object, they aren't separate.

Your linked to code is missing most of your main loop, and also lacks a `wp_reset_postdata` to cleanup at the end of your WP_Query loop

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the global variable for this.and then use this code $post->ID it will work for you.

```
      global $post
```